# Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with tinyint

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I was not able to solve my problem with existing information

```
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with tinyint
```

This problem occurs only when using mssql, Hope someone already knows the solution to this problem

When switching to mssql there were a lot of problems, it's still only one of them, because some of I managed to solve

```
@Entity
@Table
public class DoseAssignment {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 30)
@Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
private String number;

@NotNull
@Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint", nullable = false)
private Integer unit;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", 
timezone = "UTC")
private Date date;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", 
timezone = "UTC")
private Date dateOpenPlan;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", 
timezone = "UTC")
private Date dateClosePlan;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", 
timezone = "UTC")
private Date dateOpen;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", 
timezone = "UTC")
private Date dateClose;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Personal givePersonal;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private WorkMode workMode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private ProgramDangerous program;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 100)
@Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
private String content;
```

Controller

```
Page<Integer> page = repository.findId(department == null ? null : new Department(department), number, unit, workMode == null ? null : new WorkMode(workMode), apartment == null ? new Integer[]{0} : apartment, personal == null ? new Integer[]{0} : personal, program, access, outer, dateOpenPlanFrom, dateOpenPlanTo, dateOpenFrom, dateOpenTo, dateAccessFrom, dateAccessTo, protectionEquipment  == null ? new Integer[]{0}: protectionEquipment, status, pageable);
```

Query

```
@Query("select a.id from DoseAssignment a where (:id is null or a.id=:id) and (:department is null or a.department=:department) and (:unit is null or a.unit=:unit) and (:workMode is null or a.workMode=:workMode) and (:program is null or :program=false and a.program is null or :program=true and a.program is not null) and (:dateOpenPlanFrom is null or a.dateOpenPlan>=:dateOpenPlanFrom) and (:dateOpenPlanTo is null or a.dateOpenPlan<=:dateOpenPlanTo) and (:dateOpenFrom is null or a.dateOpen>=:dateOpenFrom) and (:dateOpenTo is null or a.dateOpen<=:dateOpenTo) and (:status is null or a.status=:status) and (:access is null or :access=true and a.status=4 or :access=false and not a.status=4) and ((not 0 in :apartment or not 0 in :personal or :outer is not null or :dateAccessFrom is not null or :dateAccessTo is not null or not 0 in :protectionEquipment) and a.id in (select distinct ai.id from DoseAssignment ai left join ai.protectionEquipment pei left join ai.personal pi left join ai.apartment api left join ai.assignmentAccess aai where (:department is null or ai.department=:department) and (:unit is null or ai.unit=:unit) and (:workMode is null or ai.workMode=:workMode) and (:program is null or :program=false and ai.program is null or :program=true and ai.program is not null) and (:dateOpenPlanFrom is null or ai.dateOpenPlan>=:dateOpenPlanFrom) and (:dateOpenPlanTo is null or ai.dateOpenPlan<=:dateOpenPlanTo) and (:dateOpenFrom is null or ai.dateOpen>=:dateOpenFrom) and (:dateOpenTo is null or ai.dateOpen<=:dateOpenTo) and (:status is null or ai.status=:status) and (0 in :personal or pi.id in :personal) and (0 in :apartment or api.id in :apartment) and (0 in :protectionEquipment or pei.id in :protectionEquipment) and (:dateAccessFrom is null or aai.enterDate>=:dateAccessFrom) and (:dateAccessTo is null or aai.enterDate<=:dateAccessTo) and (:outer is null or :outer=true and pi.type=2 or :outer=false and a.id not in (select distinct aii.id from DoseAssignment aii left join aii.personal pii where pii.type=2))) or not (not 0 in :apartment or not 0 in :personal or :outer is not null or :dateAccessFrom is not null or :dateAccessTo is not null or not 0 in :protectionEquipment))")
```

.

```
Page<Integer> findId(@Param("department") Department department, @Param("id") Integer id, @Param("unit") Integer unit, @Param("workMode") WorkMode workMode, @Param("apartment") Integer[] apartment, @Param("personal") Integer[] personal, @Param("program") Boolean program, @Param("access") Boolean access, @Param("outer") Boolean outer, @Param("dateOpenPlanFrom") Date dateOpenPlanFrom, @Param("dateOpenPlanTo") Date dateOpenPlanTo, @Param("dateOpenFrom") Date dateOpenFrom, @Param("dateOpenTo") Date dateOpenTo, @Param("dateAccessFrom") Date dateAccessFrom, @Param("dateAccessTo") Date dateAccessTo, @Param("protectionEquipment") Integer[] protectionEquipment, @Param("status") Integer status, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Can you show the full table definition from SQL Server?

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

A datetime2 type has a size of 6-8 bytes (and contains date and time portions of a date) vs a tinyint which is  1 byte and contain values of 0-255. You cannot fit a ten lb weight into a 1 ounce container.

Comment: can you please tell me exactly where in the code it is happening?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are assigning something of type datetime2 to a variable of type int. Please add exception handling to your code  (try catch) and the catch (this will work in a MVC app -  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e1.ToString());) will print the exact line where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives the answer here. `tinyint` and `datetime2` are incompatible. If you want to convert a `tinyint` to a `datetime2`, you'll need to firstly convert it to `datetime` (which is compatible with a `tinyint`), and then to `datetime2`.